# Android: Application is not installed on your phone

Tags: android-sdk, android, eclipse

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Работаю в eclipse, ошибок нет. Когда запускаю эмулятор, выдает ошибку:

> `[2012-08-19 14:21:31 - Foto] Installing Foto.apk...
> [2012-08-19 14:26:00 - Foto] Failed to install Foto.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
> [2012-08-19 14:26:00 - Foto] (null)
> [2012-08-19 14:26:05 - Foto] Launch canceled!`

При этом сам файл apk имеется, на телефон устанавливается, а при запуске его пишет, что приложение не установлено (Application is not installed on your phone).

Что может быть, не могу нигде найти ответа.

Манифест:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы сделали апк файл приложения и пытаетесь установить его на эмулятор и на телефон, так?
Сперва надо апк подписать.

Comment: Не надо, подписать надо перед публикацией в маркет. Просто перезагрузи эклипс, адб, подключи еще раз все, пересобери проект...

Comment: Да, вы правильно меня поняли, я осваиваю для себя андроид, пробую камеру. Приложение апк при запуске эмулятора формируется, эмулятор запускается, в нем в списке приложений видно мое, при запуске выдает ошибку приложение не установлено на ваш телефон. В принципе, спасибо за отклик, я разобрался в чем дело - дело в манифесте, поустанавливал permission куда надо и куда не надо))) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если это все, что есть в вашем манифесте - конечно он говорит application not installed, ведь в манифестее она не объявлена! Нужна секция `<application>`. Прочитайте целиком [гайд по манифесту](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)